# Labels automatically changing position from main view to Print Composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, zoom

I am working on a basic river map and when switching to the Print Composer, many of my labels are randomly moved. And not only they are changed on the default view on the Print Composer, but they keep randomly changing when adjusting the Zoom Level at the bottom right-hand side. Checking some other answers to similar problems here and on QGIS repository, I have tried:

- Having the same scale on the main view and the Print composer: done and no success.
- Setting the size of my labels on map units insted of, for example, milimitres: done and no success.
- Untick "Features act as obstacles": done and no success.
- Locking the scale on the main view: done and no success.
- Setting high priority on the layer's labels: done and no success.
- Setting an exact anchor point and the Placement Behaviour on Strict: done and no success.

At this point, I am absolutely clueless. Any ideas why this keeps happening?

**Main View:**
[image]

**Print Composer:**
[image]

Comment: the scale seems different to me

Comment: They are the same scale

Comment: They are clearly not in the images you have posted

Comment: You do realise that they were screenshots of the map, don't you? Anyway, I have updated the images, now displaying the maps AND the scale in both views, so you can see that they are clearly the same.

Comment: Have you tried a fixed reference scale for the layer's rendering properties?

Comment: Maybe allow for a larger map item size (at the same scale) in the print layout. Also check out the layout's label rendering settings (allow labels to be cut off by edge of map) - i think it's the little label icon above the map item info panel on the bottom right of your second screenshot.

Comment: Tried the solutions by the previous users and unfortunately, none of them worked.